# IBOutlet Collection Labels displaying one

Tags: ios, label, uicollectionview

I have a IBOutlet Collection view hooked up to 10 labels after pulling objects from a Parse query. My problem is that for some reason it logs 10 different object Ids but only displays one of the object Ids through the collection view. Here is the code I have:PFQuery *query =

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        int i = 0;
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            for (UILabel *EventLabel in self.EventTitles){
                (EventLabel *)self.EventTitles[i]= object.objectId;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Does anyone see a problem with the code for it to only display one rather than the 10?

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you execute this cycle

```
for (UILabel *EventLabel in self.EventTitles){
   EventLabel.text = object.objectId;
}
```

within this other cycle

```
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
}
```

It means that the first one gets hexecuted every time you get a new object from objects. And each time you get a object from objects you overwrite all the labels with the same objectID. The effect is that at end all the labels will show the objectID of the last object analysed. You should do something like the following instead:

```
int i = 0;
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
   if (i >= [self.EventTitles count]) break;//to make sure we only write up to the max number of UILabels available in EventTitles
   (UILabel *) self.EventTitles[i].text = object.objectId;//I assume the "objectId" property of object is an NSString!
   i++;
}
```

You should rename "EventTitles" to "eventTitles" - it's a common rule that Class names start with a capital letter but instance variables ones don't. It will run anyway if you don't change it but it's a good think to do across your code.

Comment: I revised the code a bit but it gives me an error on the EventLabel line saying 'expected expression'.. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it fails saying 'expected expression'

Comment: Sorry last night I wrote very quickly and typed a couple of mistakes - just updated my answer. Try now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot that looks great, however I have one last question... I know that the objectId needs to be a NSString but where is it I need to declare that string? Because right now it is telling me build failed due to 'Property 'text' not found on object of type Id'

Comment: Are you casting self.EventTitles[i].text writing (UILabel *) in front of it. If you don't add the cast the compiler will warn you as text is a property of UILabel but not of a generic object (id).